# Scrape data from multiple URLs

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have a dataframe of two variables and 49 observations that looks like this:

```
Link                                  URL
1   20 political parties urge govt... http://www.mmtimes.com/index.php/national-news/27265-20-political-parties-urge-govt-to-act-on-rakhine-issue.html
2   Tens of thousands protest across.. http://www.mmtimes.com/index.php/national-news/27236-tens-of-thousands-protest-across-rakhine-over-security-issues.html
```

I would like to use scrape byline and article text for the articles and create a data frame like so:

```
data.frame(title=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".contentheading")),
       authordate=html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".create")),
       text=html_text(html_nodes(pg, "p")),
       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I can get the data for each article using:

```
read_html(df$URL[1]) %>%
html_nodes(".create") %>%
html_text()
```

How do I scrape all the data from the URLs using the column from my current data frame (df$URL)?

**Update:** I am now using the following to try and get the data:

```
mmtimes_data <- data.frame(title=character(),author=character(),text=character())

for (i in url) {
mmtimes <- read_html(i)
title <- mmtimes %>% html_nodes(".contentheading") %>% html_text() %>%     as.character()
author <- mmtimes %>% html_nodes("created") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
text <- mmtimes %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
temp <- data.frame(title, authordate, text)
mmtimes_data <- rbind(mmtimes_data,temp)
cat("*")
}
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options =     options) : 
expecting a single value
```

**Update #2**

I solved this using the following code:

```
mmtimes_data <- data.frame(title=character(),author=character(),text=character())

for (i in links) {
mmtimes <- read_html(i)
title <- mmtimes %>% html_nodes(".contentheading") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
author <- mmtimes %>% html_nodes(".create") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
text <- mmtimes %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text() %>% as.character()
temp <- data.frame(title, author, text)
mmtimes_data <- rbind(mmtimes_data,temp)
cat("*")
}
```

Comment: With a for loop or lapply.

Comment: I only get 'Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 500' with those urls